# What permission needed for php?

Tags: php, postfix

I would like to check postfix active queue. I php script I use

```
$active = shell_exec('/bin/ls -1 /var/spool/postfix/active | /usr/bin/wc -l');
```

But in log I see

```
/bin/ls: cannot open directory /var/spool/postfix/active: Permission denied
```

What group I need to add php or postfix to avoid this error ?

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian, PHP is run by default on the www-data:www-data user. So /var/spool/postfix/active is not accessible as it is owned by postfix.

So you must go root before doing that.

It is maybe easier to run a `mailq | egrep ^\*|wc -l` to have the same result without the problem because mailq is a link to sendmail, which is run by root.

Comment: perfect!  but why you use egrep?  mailq | wc -l - the same result or not?

Comment: Try it ! The answer is no ! You have 4 lines by mail (active, deferred...). The star means active mails only.